# sensor_msgs in Windows

Tags: ros, image, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have images coming from a camera into a Windows PC (through an sdk that only works in Windows) and would like to publish the image as a message in ROS. I've used the image type from sensor_msgs in Linux and would like to publish the same message in Windows, but I haven't found the sensor_msgs package. Has the code for sensor_msgs been ported to Windows yet (or is it planned in the near future)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30810/sensor_msgs-in-windows/) by [Jon](https://answers.ros.org/users/1247/jon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2012-03-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can follow progress of the msvc build on Fuerte at the following links:

- [WinRos](http://www.ros.org/wiki/win_ros)
- [Msvc Build Environment - Fuerte](http://www.ros.org/wiki/win_ros/Msvc%20Build%20Environment%20-%20Fuerte)

It's already compiling common_msgs (including sensor_msgs). We'll start packaging an sdk (libs and headers) sometime shortly.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2012-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2